# What are the general properties of a common wireless sensor node while designing a MAC protocol?

Tags: sensors, wireless, omnet++

What are the properties of a wireless sensor node ?

From Omnet++ manual i came to know that

```
simple wirelessnode
{
gates:
input radioIn;
parameters:
...........
}
```

Though the node have only input gate , how it sending data to other node?
if the node is wireless how the sensor node connected ?
How to define a region around a wireless sensor node for reach another node in range?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending, you can think with a DODAG : take a tree, put the root as the gate. The gate gathers the data of its children, each of those children gathring themselves the data of their children ... the leaves are the nodes that need the more hops to be reached from the root.

Here you would need, among others : the power of the transmitting, the power of the receiving chip (so that if the sending node is too far away then the receiving node won't catch its frame for example, as pointed by user4786271), a protocol to route them (so that if a node has 2 other nodes in range of rank n-1, to know which one it will use).

Try to dig into some open source WSN simulators implementing protocols, you could get a lot of info. For example :  https://bitbucket.org/6tisch/simulator/src

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, there is no such thing like "general properties" for a given module when designing a protocol.

Usually the decision of the module properties that you are going to use, is strongly related to what that node is supposed to do as part of your protocol.

If your node is never going to communicate, there is no point in adding a gate to it.

---

> Though the node have only input gate , how it sending data to other
>   node?

You don't have to strictly adhere to the design that you have seen. Maybe in that case the nodes only need to receive messages. In your case you might want to define an output gate.

---

> if the node is wireless how the sensor node connected ?

Do not view the gates as physical entities, but rather as interfaces which are capable of communicating through links. Do you see a cable link between your mobile phone and the basestation? Probably not, because they are connected through a wireless link. So your mobile phone has an interface for wireless link. See where I am going? In your case you will need a gate with wireless link.

---

> How to define a region around a wireless sensor node for reach another
>   node in range?

Hmm, based on your propagation model the received signal power will depend on the distance, right? You can check the received power for the MAC frame and dismiss it if it is below a given threshold.

Or, if you work on the application layer -- which you don't -- you can embed location information in your packets and then perform pairwise distance comparison to decide packets from which sender to consider or drop.